# Switching between Vin and regulating voltage when unit turn on

Tags: mosfet, analog-switch

I am trying to find way to switch between power supply on common pin of overlay (or button). I came with simple p channel Mosfet circuit I just want make sure if this will work. (all overlay button works with same common power, and in order to detect logic high I need voltage around 3.3V in 5V logic) Similar to Relay

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5hWqL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Basic info: This is Battery power 2xAA cell with boost regulator which convert to 5V. Unit use overlay as buttons. The overlay short desire button with common pin which connected to power source. we use overlay "ON" button to pull enable pin of regulator high so turn on device, because of that common pin need to be connect to battery when unit is off.
The issue start when unit turn on we need change the common pin to 5V because when overlay button clicked we need 3.3V to detect high logic , and 2XAA is around 3.2 and less.

Flow Diagram

[image]

Comment: pretty sure you don't want an ancient LM7905 when 1. you need 3.3V out (and get 5V instead; microcontrollers these days don't run off 5V, usually, and especially these for battery usage probably aren't) and 2. you're running from batteries - the LM79xx / LM78xx aren't low in quiescent current (they use like 0.5mA to 1mA even when nothing is attached. You can get boost converters that use less – so you gain exactly nothing).

Comment: Sorry. I know I am not using that part it seems it didnt save my drawing, I am trying to edit it again

Comment: Convert all logic design to low voltage is preferred.

Comment: What do you mean by `overlay`?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I like to convert it to 3.3 or 3.0 logic but this IC need to be 200mV under the regulated voltage.(Manual 5.2.1 Vin>Vout)   "For VIN > VOUT, the output voltage will not remain in
regulation. VIN > VOUT is an unusual situation for a
boost converter, and there is a common issue when
two alkaline cells (2 x 1.6V typical) are used to boost to
3.0V output. A minimum headroom of approximately
200 to 300 mV between VOUT and VIN "
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005253A.pdf

Comment: @Andyaka Similar to these
https://www.google.com/search?q=overlay+membrane+with+button&hl=en&sxsrf=APq-WBujNFe0P2ZipSrqmdIKl9LybWD3wg:1646760588037&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiM7ISfhbf2AhUBGDQIHc8lBOQQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1536&bih=750&dpr=1.25#imgrc=OI_N4sZwOkIIXM

Comment: I think the term you're looking for there is "dropout voltage", i.e. the minimum difference between the input voltage and output voltage on the regulator.

Answer (score 0):

It is wiser to change design to lowest voltage.  Then choose best converter for power source specified.

If Vin=1.9 to 3.2V < 1A , Vo=3.0V consider [this design I made](https://webench.ti.com/appinfo/webench/scripts/SDP.cgi?ID=22BD9F4FC4D4AD04)

Yet lower Vout is possible.

Comment: is great option to use, but unfortunately this part is not in stock so I can not use it, that is whole reason I had to go with microchip part

Comment: I see lots of stock in Asia from many sources

Comment: Could you please send me the link

Comment: https://www.digipart.com/part/TPS61230A  pls send goodies

Comment: find the goodies yet?  مرکز آمار ایران